# VS Code Path Intellisense not working in Mac Big Sur 11

Tags: path, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

[image]

My VS Code is up to date but I'm not sure why the intellisense is not working properly.. its only showing the first file/folder instead of the list of files/folders when I press control + space.

I tried the solution mentioned in this link but still not working. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103855